# "Value does not fall within the expected range" Error when trying to add user to a sitegroup through REST API SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, groups

I want to add a user to the members group of a SP site. Unfortunately I always get the above mentioned error when I use the LoginName format that is documented in the API reference. When I use simple UPN or email, I get User not unique or not found.

**I should propably have added that I come from an outside source, i.e. our Servicenow Instance and authenticate through an OAUTH token.**

Here is the REST call:
Endpoint: `http://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/_api/web/sitegroups(5)/users`

Header:

```
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

Content:

```
{ 
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User'},
    'LoginName':'i:0#.f|membership|fname.lname@xyz.com'
}
```

Result:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}}
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Here are some shots from the setup (within Servicenow):

[image: Preprocess]

[image: Rest Step]

[image: Result]

Comment: You have i:0#.f... written. Du you realy have FormsBased authentication? If yes, is "membership" the actual name of the issuer? please have a look at Claims Encoding at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx

Comment: I got the username from a different API call looking up the user info, so I guess that is correct.

Comment: Is the user already known in the site collection ? If not you should first call /web/ensureuser

Comment: That said the http status code may help

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code. I just tried this at my end and it is working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/siteName/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="addUserToGroup()"> Add User To Group </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addUserToGroup() {
        var addUserToGroupEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(38)/users";

        var payload = JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' },
            'LoginName': 'i:0#.f|membership|meganb@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: addUserToGroupEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: payload,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("User Added to Group successfully!");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

You can check the `LoginName` format using site users endpoint. open below URL in browser tab:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/spconnect/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Title,LoginName
```

**Example Output**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:LoginName>i:0#.f|membership|meganb@tenant.onmicrosoft.com</d:LoginName>
    <d:Title>Megan Bowen</d:Title>
</m:properties><m:properties>
    <d:LoginName>i:0#.f|membership|diegos@tenant.onmicrosoft.com</d:LoginName>
    <d:Title>Diego Siciliani</d:Title>
</m:properties>
```

Comment: Verify and use correct user LoginName and group ID from your SharePoint site.

Comment: I get both from previos API calls.
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(ID) and
.../_api/web?$expand=AssociatedOwnerGroup,AssociatedMemberGroup,AssociatedVisitorGroup

Comment: Did you try code given in my answer? Is it working for you? Try to copy data payload & headers as it.

Comment: I tried to replicate in my tool, not sure where I would run this script. See my edit in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me

```
var groupId = 6; //SharePoint group id
var userLoginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|testuser_01@TENANT.onmicrosoft.com'; //Login name of the user to be added
$.ajax(
{
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/GetById("+ groupId +")/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(
    {
        '__metadata':
        {
            'type': 'SP.User'
        },
        'LoginName': userLoginName
    }),
    headers:
    {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr)
    {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        console.log("Failed");
    }
});
```

You can get the correct format/value for LoginName using the browser dev tools. Screenshot added below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use the REST capabilities that are built into SharePoint, you construct a RESTful HTTP request by using the OData standard, which corresponds to the client object model API you want to use.

The `client.svc` web service handles the HTTP request and serves the appropriate response in either Atom or JSON format.